# Return all rows from primary dataframe above the 1st matching row (from top of secondary dataframe)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have two dataframe like mentioned below:

Primary_df:

```
        Symbol                   Subject   Broadcast Date/Time
0   CUMMINSIND  Financial Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 18:31
1          IGL  Financial Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 17:16
2   MANAPPURAM  Financial Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 16:10
3   MANAPPURAM            Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 16:00
4     JSWSTEEL  Financial Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 15:18
```

Secondary_df:

```
        Symbol                   Subject   Broadcast Date/Time
0   MANAPPURAM  Financial Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 16:10
```

Logic should check for exact matching row in Primary_df from Secondary_df (contains only 1 row) and return Result_df.

I want Result_df as:

```
        Symbol                   Subject   Broadcast Date/Time
0   CUMMINSIND  Financial Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 18:31
1          IGL  Financial Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 17:16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) withnew column and filter by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
a = Primary_df.assign(A=np.arange(len(Primary_df))).merge(Secondary_df)['A']

df = Primary_df.iloc[:a.iat[0]]
print (df)
       Symbol                   Subject Broadcast Date/Time
0  CUMMINSIND  Financial Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 18:31
1         IGL  Financial Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 17:16
```

If get:

> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

it means no row matched and need more general solution with `next` for return `0` for no match:

```
df = Primary_df.iloc[: next(iter(a), 0)]
```

Comment: Excellent answer Sir. Thanks.